# Reading ZipEntry containing special characters while using Java SE6

Tags: java, character-encoding, zip

**UPDATED WITH SOLUTION, see at bottom**

**Requirement**:
Process a ZIP file in Java SE 6 that contains files with special characters in the file names. As the encoding (of the ZIP producer) is not UTF-8, special characters get encoded. Therefore I would like to correct special characters into their proper code.

**Issue**:
The ZIP contains a file called `abcüabc.txt` .
The entry gets processed via `java.util.zip.ZipEntry` and when printing out single characters I see these characters (bytes):

`ü` gets encoded as
`u` followed by a
`¨`

**Question**:
So I would like to know how I can replace that `u¨` into `ü` or maybe `ue`:

What I already tried and did not work out:
`name.replaceAll("u\\¨", "ue");`
or
`name.replaceAll("ü", "ue");`

**Original Source Code (not working)**:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/me/Desktop/test.zip"));
ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(is);
ZipEntry zipEntry = null;
while ((zipEntry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    String name = zipEntry.getName(); // reading abcüabc.txt
    System.out.println("pos 3: "+name.charAt(3));
    System.out.println("pos 4: "+name.charAt(4));
    System.out.println("is equal to ¨: "+Character.toString(name.charAt(4)).equals("¨"));
}
```

Output:

```
pos 3: u
pos 4:¨
is equal to ¨: false
```

**Notes on my environment**:

Zip produced under Mac OS X 10.6.8
Java SE 6: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)

**SOLUTION**

Obviously, the ZIP producer (in my case Mac OSX) converts special characters into a decomposed format. So a `ü` gets decomposed into `u¨`.
While extracting the file names form the ZIP, we would like to convert back from the decomposed to the composed format, so we only have to insert a normalization into our source code from above:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/me/Desktop/test.zip"));
ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(is);
ZipEntry zipEntry = null;
while ((zipEntry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    String name = zipEntry.getName(); // reading abcüabc.txt
    System.out.println("pos 3: "+name.charAt(3));
    System.out.println("pos 4: "+name.charAt(4));
    System.out.println("contains ü: "+name.contains("ü"));
    name = Normalizer.normalize(name, Form.NFC);
    System.out.println("contains ü: "+name.contains("ü"));
}
```

Output:

```
pos 3: u
pos 4:¨
contains ü: false
contains ü: true
```

Comment: If memory serves, [`java.util.jar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html) uses UTF-8-encoded entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a `¨` ([U+00A8 DIAERESIS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a8/index.htm)), but the [U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/308/index.htm).

The character is splitted this way because Mac Os stores file names in the Normalization Form D, which Decomposes characters like this.

You can compose it back like so:

```
String name = zipEntry.getName(); 
name = Normalizer.normalize(name, Form.NFC);
```

More about [normalization forms](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)

The difference between the diaeresises is how they modify or don't modify the previous base character:

```
    System.out.println( "u" + (char)0xA8); //u¨
    System.out.println( "u" + (char)0x0308); //ü
```

Comment: Thanks! As I just tested: using `name = Normalizer.normalize(name, Form.NFC);` will deliver `true` for `name.contains("ü")`... great!  But you say that Mac OS uses Form D, why do I have to use `Form.NFC` and not `Form.NFD` ? Just for curiosity...

Comment: @basZero Because we want to convert to `NFC` (Normal Form Composed), where `ü` is a single character. What you have been given initially is in NFD (Normal Form Decomposed), and we want to compose it back. Get it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apache ant` solve the encoding problem.

Import `org.apache.tools.zip.*`

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(fileName,"you encoding");// you encoding like utf-8 
Enumeration emu = zipFile.getEntries();


while(emu.hasMoreElements()){
  ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) emu.nextElement();
  // do something
}
```

Ant project does not provide an online doc, here is another doc http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.7.0/

Comment: I was looking for a solution that works with every ZIP, independent on the client program that produced the ZIP.

Comment: `org.apache.tools.zip.*` can work well on most ZIP file. It's there a solution works well with all ZIP?

Comment: `java.util.zip.*` works for all my cases (zipping on Mac OS, Windows 98 and 8, Ubuntu 9+10)